# Долго отрабатывает SQL запрос c условием datetime <= '2021-06-20T21:00:00.000Z'

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему долго отрабатывает запрос в зависимости от формата даты.

Запрос 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_table`
WHERE
    `my_table`.`timestamp` >= '2021-06-20T21:00:00.000Z'
    AND `my_table`.`timestamp` <= '2021-07-20T21:59:00.000Z'
```

Работает около 3.5 секунд.

Запрос 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_table`
WHERE
    `my_table`.`timestamp` >= '2021-06-20 21:00:00'
    AND `my_table`.`timestamp` <= '2021-07-20 21:59:00'
```

отрабатывает около 0.3 с.

Поле timestamp тип: datetime

Буду рад ссылкe на документацию

Comment: В первом случае контекст операции - строковый, во втором - дата-время.

Comment: *Буду рад ссылкe на документацию* [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)